# NunitConsoleRunner test using mono on windows

Tags: windows, mono, nunit, nunit-console

I have installed mono and added mono/bin directory to PATH.

The way I am running tests:
mono nunit3-console.exe C:\Test\bin\Debug\Test.dll

output:

[image: console output]

I tried with --framework=mono and mono-4.0 but it does not work.

The assembly is compiled by xbuild.

Edit: Running from mono command prompt - same result

Comment: It could be a bug in our (NUnit's) mono detection on Windows. It doesn't get tested enough with every Mono update. Curious, does it work if you run with the `--inprocess` command line option to the NUnit console?

Comment: This might end up being better dealt with as an NUnit GitHub issue, https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues

Comment: @rprouse Except that it's now github.com/nunit/nunit-console/issues :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nunit-console issue https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/issues/34

This was found in code-review a while back. No users have complained about it up to now, so it's priority was low. I just increased the priority.